# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-ws

I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError for PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping. I'm using Spring-ws-core 2.4.0. Previously I was using WAS Server and I didn't have any issues, now I'm using Tomcat 9 and I'm getting these exceptions. Any idea what I need to do?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:632)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:680)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:551)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:492)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:1998)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: My guess is that you have a packaging issue.  Spring Boot creates an executable JAR and has Tomcat running inside it.  You need to make sure that Maven creates an executable JAR will all the dependencies inside it, available on the CLASSPATH.

Comment: Can you add pom.xml for clarification ?